# Get the number of non-hidden rows in a table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to count the number of rows in my table that are not hidden.  I can tell if a row is hidden by checking the style of the `tr` attribute: `<tr style="display: none; ">`.  How do you calculate this using jquery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use the :visible   selector.

```
$('tr:visible').length;
```

here is a fiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/cX6jb/

Comment: what version are you using?  there was a bug in very old jquery, but it was fixed in 1.4.2 i believe

Answer (score 5):

The [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) will only select the visible items.

```
var count = $('#your-table tr:visible').length;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D4bKZ/)

If you already have a variable that holds your rows, you can also use the `filter` method.

```
var $rows = $('#your-table tr'),
    visibleCount = $rows.filter(':visible').length;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('tr').filter(':visible').length
```

Tada! Note: Visible is a jQuery selector, so it is much faster to get your elements using a valid css selector then filtering them.

[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: that will give the length all the things inside the tr that are visible.  so, if each row has 2 td it will return 4.  definitely not what they want.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an easier way, but you could do this

```
var a = $('tr').length;
var b = $('tr[style="display:none;"]').length;
alert(a - b);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YV3cy/

Answer (score 1):

If you find out specific table do this

```
$("#tableid tr:visible").length
```